# Remote debugging of net.core app doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, remote-debugging

I have a dot net core app, and I use Debug -> attach to process on azure websites remote server:
[image]

I attach to dotnet.exe process, and I can see breakpoint is red, which means symbols are loaded and ready for debug.

Issue is when I hit the website, nothing happens in visual studio, so it doesn't hit the breakpoint for some reason. Is this correct way to attach to process to remotely debug net core app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out you have to attach w3wp.exe AND dotnet.exe. Problem solved.

Comment: I was looking EVERYWHERE for the solution to this problem. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Have you published a Debug version of your Azure site? If you need to attach to the Azure website (called App) and step through your code, you have to do a publish with `Debug` configuration so the PDBs are copied over.

[image]

#### Source: MSDN / [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio)